# Everytime i debug with eclipse I get a Nullpointer exception?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception

When i debug my application on jboss or tomcat i get a NullpointerException the line i place the first breakpoint in. I used eclipse -clean, restarted my machine, ... no way. just can't get rid of it.

stacktrace

```
    2011-02-02 15:13:34,848 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-192.168.1.128-8080-2) #{userController.doLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.FacesException: #{userController.doLogin}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:387)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at de.simplefact.navv.gui.common.viewstate.ViewExpiredFilter.doFilter(ViewExpiredFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.simplefact.navv.gui.common.controller.UserController.doLogin(UserController.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        ... 39 more
```

Comment: Not to put you on the spot, but maybe you've got some line of code which unexpectedly throws a NullPointerException.  It'd be worth double checking.  Stuff like that has happened to me before.

Comment: stacktrace - see above.. i am very sure that there's no nullpointer in my sources .. no matter where i place that breakpoint - it'll blow up the application.

Comment: So, what is in UserController.java at line 58, and why could it be null ?

Comment: mToken = null;  // mToken is a member variable of type String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nooooooooooooo... If you're a really smart ass guy like i am *cough*, you'll debug using expressions. one of my expressions was "throw new NullpointerException();".. so everytime i reached the first debug mark this expression was executed and forced the application to crash.

.. Thinking further you may use this to bug your colleagues. When your colleague heads for a coffee, add some "throw new NullpointerException();" to his expressions in the debug perspective of eclipse and then find out how smart he is ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The UserController value is null, so when JSF evaluates `#{UserController.whatever}` the NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: running without any breakpoints will cause no problems.. so i assume it has to deal with the debugging..

Comment: ørn: no problems running without breakpoints! that's the confusing part.

Comment: Are you running the official JBoss and Tomcat connectors with Eclipse JEE edition or something else?

Comment: ørn: looking at my answer your question should have been something like: what iq you're running your brain with .. less or more than 40?  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to assigned a dummy value on UserController.java:58 to distinguish if still exist? Where is your breakpoint? Is at UserController.java:58 also?

Btw, from the beginning on the stack trace, it shows that it is not an error but WARNING. Did u configure Eclipse on the debugging options on how to handle WARNING message with NPE?

Comment: exactly where the breakpoint is, the nullpointer occurs.. so i may also place it in some filter or converter - causes to crash the app when reaching the breakpoint. maybe the "warning" is something to have a closer look.. i used some default configuration for the logging..